# Can module names in Python end with an underscore?

Tags: python, module, package, naming, pep

Below you can find an example of the problem that I'm facing:

---

**project**:

- package:

  - `xml.py`

---

**xml.py**:

`import xml.etree.ElementTree as Et`

---

My module named *xml.py* is getting confused with the *xml* package when I import it, now my question is:

Can I name my module in such a way that won't interfere with the package name, but at the same time would be compliant with the PEP8 styling guide (e.g: `xml_.py`. I have seen this naming convention for variables but I am not sure it is a good practice to name modules like this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) guide on module names states:

> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is discouraged.

Moreover, another [PEP-8 guideline](https://pep8.org/#descriptive-naming-styles) states:

> single_trailing_underscore_: used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword, e.g.:

... and that's exactly why you are doing it, and not just "for fun".
So, even though it is not explicitly stated as a naming guidelines for modules, I assume we can adapt it to all Python naming conventions. So I think you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

modules (filenames) should have short, all-lowercase names, and they can contain underscores;

Pep8 documentation, so yes you can :)

Comment: That's the thing, I am a bit confused because I haven't seen a module named like this (underscore at the end) in any project till now, despite being said that "Modules can contain underscores".

Comment: I agree with you, I just tell him that it is possible, after it is true that it is not a common practice